# Stuck email in outbox when sending emai by MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using MFMailComposeViewController to send email with attached files, and everything is ok

But sometime, the email stuck in outbox.

I do not know the reason.

What's the limit of receiver and max size of apple mail?

Comment: Which email client you are using and on which network-wifi, 3G, 4G???

Comment: @rishi: i'm using wifi and implement MFMailComposeViewController on my application to allow user can send email from my app.

Comment: which email is configured on your device, some time gmail has certain issue with wi-fi? I doubt you are using gmail?

Comment: My email is : xxxx@bellsouth.net, it's yahoo.  I did not have this issues if i use Apple Mail

Comment: did some of you have the same problems?

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem!
Go to Settings -> Mail -> Accounts(email) -> yourAccount(mine was Gmail) -> type in your password

Possibly you have updated your password and native app can't send messages now.

Then go to iPhones Native App and check outgoing email. Try to resend them, should be working now.